# Subspaces and scalar multiplication (zero)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

when we are checking whether a subset v is a subspace or not , we search for two main things :

1. closed under addition
2. closed under scalar multiplication

my 2 question are

> does scalar multiplication include  zero ?
>
> does addition include the additive inverse?

as if it does then any subset that doesn't include the zero matrix won't be considered a subset

Comment: "When we are checking whether a subset v is a **subset** or not"... a subset is always a subset.  The question is usually in this context whether it is a sub**space** or not.  "...any subset that doesn't include the zero *vector* won't be considered a sub*space*"

Comment: subspace thing was a typo(fixed it ) . thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is affirmative. And, yes, it follows from this that, if a subset $S$ of a vector space is such that $0\notin S$, then $S$ is *not* a subspace.